# Exporting mbed application to uVision

Tags: c, static, embedded, inline, mbed

I was programming with mbed's online compiler, but now I need debugging support and last night I exported to uVision 4. There seems to be an error when I compile the official libraries though.

mbed/KL25Z/gpio_object.h(33): warning:  #260-D: explicit type issing ("int" assumed)
mbed/KL25Z/gpio_object.h(33): error:  #65: expected a ";"

This code is the same on the other platforms as well. The code at line 33 looks like this...

```
static inline void gpio_write(gpio_t *obj, int value) {
    if (value)
        *obj->reg_set = obj->mask;
    else
        *obj->reg_clr = obj->mask;
}
```

I tried surrounding the if-else with braces and that didn't work, so now I don't know what to do...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default C compilation is ISO C90 where the `inline` keyword is not valid.  Use either:

- the `__inline` C90 extension,
- C++ compilation or
- C99 compilation.

Without either of those, the C90 compiler parses the code as a declaration of a static variable called "inline" without an explicit type and a missing semi-colon.

Comment: I'm new to uVision, where do I change it to C99 or C++?

Comment: K, so I tried both c99 and cpp and they gave me a ton of errors. It seems to recognize --inline, but still gives me the same error...

Comment: That's `__inline` not `--inline` replacing the keyword `inline` in the code not a command line switch (just to be clear).  Moreover `static` and `__inline` together makes little sense - remove `static` (or `inline` - either way one or the other not both).  If you get errors with C++ or C99 compilation, then post another question if it is of concern - it may be indicative of other issues.

Comment: Ahh okay, well I removed inline and it worked. Not sure if that was the right solution, but I'll try `__inline` when I get home.